# rsync doesn't sync files

Tags: cygwin, rsync

I'm using rsync(with Cygwin)  to sync 2 local folder 
The folder contains binary files

I'm using the following command

rsync.exe -av dir1/ dir2/

but the files in dir2 where only partially update, there are few different files

does anybody know of a problem with rsync on windows?
should i use some other flags

10'xs

Comment: Best of over at super user for this sort of question.

Answer (score 2):

i am use rsync.exe with

```
rsync.exe -vrt dir1/ dir2/
```

and at first dir1 is :

```
new text.txt
new text 2.txt
```

and first of all dir2 is empty, maybe, not should create even.
At the end dir2 is

```
new text.txt
new text 2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

rsync will skip files that have the same size and modification date. If you suspect this might be the problem, try adding the **-I** (or **--ignore-times**) option to the command-line.